# how to send sms through WAVECOM multiport usb modem using C#

Tags: c#

Can anybody tell me how to send sms through `WAVECOM` multiport usb moden using C# ?
I installed the drivers and connect a sim card. but I have no idea how to send sms from it.
an A-type USB cable is connected the PC and the other end is B-type usb connector. I am using
TATA docomo sim card for connection

```
[PC] ----------------------------------------------------> [MODEM]
== A-type USB output          B-type USB input
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: I guess you need to send it AT commands over the rs232 port. For a starter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101217/rs232-serial-port-communication-c-sharp-win7-net-framework-3-5-sp1