# Sending data through RS232 using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a device that can communicate trough RS232. and it comes with the communication protocol to access the data.

I'm writing a simple c# program to connect and get the status from the device and Im not quite sure whether Im on the right path.

Below is the sample they have given.

**Command 50: status request**

The status request command is used to request the register response package, without later actions that may alter the status of the system.

0     1     2   3    4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11   12   13
STX  ADDR ADDR CMOD "5" "0" "0" "3" TKN1 TKN0 TYPE CHKL CHKH 0X0D

STX = Start byte of the frame (0x02)

ADDR = TE550 logical address [2 bytes]

CMOD = CMOD to refer [1 byte] 
TKN1/0 = Frame identification bytes [2 bytes]

TYPE = Selection byte for customizable box (RiqA/B)* [1 byte]

CHKH/L = Checksum [2 bytes]

END = End byte of the frame (0x0D)

**Example:
status request from PC to TE550 (address 01), CMOD 1, Token 01, Type 1**

[0x02]0115003011EE[0x0D]

I can connect to the com port using the serial port.

I am referring to the answer by DesMy "[RS232 serial port communication c# win7 .net framework 3.5 sp1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101217/rs232-serial-port-communication-c-sharp-win7-net-framework-3-5-sp1)"

So far Im not getting any signal once write to the COM port. However I'm not quite sure whether Im sending the correct data to the com port. Currently Im sending data as below

comPort.Write("20115003011EE3");

Any help / sample code etc would be much appreciated.

public void ConnectRS232 ()

```
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.Open();



            mySerialPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;

          mySerialPort.Write("20115003011EE3");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ex.Message;    
        }

    }

    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(DisplayToUI), new object[] { indata });


    }

    private void DisplayToUI(string displayData)
    {
        textBox1.Text += displayData.Trim();


    }
```

Comment: hi, can you post the code you have done so far

Comment: I have shared the code so far.. any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do I need to convert the data to byte[] before write to serial port?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with low level port I/O, **characters are not bytes**!

Do not send strings. Create a byte stream containing the correct characters and send that.

[In .NET characters are shorts, not bytes. Doesn't matter. Use bytes.]