# Read SerialPort buffer using DataReceived event handler

Tags: c#, delphi, serial-port

I come from Delphi with the following code:

```
// COM port received data processing
procedure TMainForm.CommPortReceiveData(Sender: TObject; Buffer: Pointer;
  BufferLength: Word);
var
  redata: array[0..290] of byte;
begin
  move(Buffer^, pchar(@redata)^, BufferLength); // copy data from COM buffer
  end;
end;
```

And I want to do the same thing in C#:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] byteReadData = new byte[290];
    serialPort1 = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.Write(indata);
    // copy data from COM buffer ???
}
```

I don't know how to take the data from SerialDataReceivedEventArgs and copy it to my byte array byteReadData.

This is what I write to serial port: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfLI1.png
This is what I should be reading from serial port but it fails: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PllQi.png

Comment: You get the best responses on SO showing you have made some effort yourself. A starting point may be to look at the [SerialPort class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation - specifically the Read methods - you will find examples there. Or look for a tutorial like this top of list with googling ".net serialport tutorial" : http://www.instructables.com/id/Serial-Port-Programming-With-NET/

Comment: I usually look on MSDN website for documentation and some examples, but  couldn't find any example for Class SerialDataReceivedEventArgs.

Comment: If the data to be received is only text, it is OK with ReadExisting(). 
However, if you receive binary data, you can read the size of the data in the receive buffer with the BytesToRead property, specify it as the data size, specify the byte array as the receive area, and call the Read() method.

Comment: @kunif I'm actually reading binary data. My problem is that I don't understand where are the equivalent "Buffer: Pointer" and "BufferLength: Word" in my serialPort1_DataReceived event parameters. Could you please write me your answer refered to my code? Currently it writes nothing, so there must be something wrong in it (my indata gets printed empty).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use dataReceived event of the SerialPort Port Object in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466474/how-do-i-use-datareceived-event-of-the-serialport-port-object-in-c)

Comment: "Buffer: Pointer" and "BufferLength: Word" are the address and size of the buffer prepared by the caller of Delphi's CommPortReceiveData() and are not directly related to the contents of C#.  "Buffer: Pointer" is an address to store the read data, which is a combination of the first parameter and the second parameter of the C# Read() method.  In the C# code of the question, the byteReadData variable and the starting index in it(usually 0).  "BufferLength: Word" is the size of the byteReadData variable(290), it is not used in the Read() method.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I copied the code from that link: https://i.imgur.com/fWbSxnu.png my expected output byte sequence is different tho: https://i.imgur.com/WQNhmqa.png

Comment: No it is the same, the IDE shows you decimal values while your monitoring tool is showing hex values....

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice. What if I want to display them in hexa format tho?

Comment: Please learn to search on this site ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354508/800214

Comment: I found it: BitConverter.ToString, sure your link didn't help.